# How do I stop a while loop when ANY keystroke is registered in c#

Tags: c#, while-loop, user-input, keypress, keystroke

I've been searching around for an answer but all I can find are solutions for if a user inputs a specific key. I want ANY key that is pressed to halt the repeating message in the loop. So if no key is pressed, the loop's message keeps going.

```
do
{
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWAKE UP."); //repeats forever until
    }       
} 
while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape); //here the key that stops the loop is Escape

return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer do/while loop is causing your inner loop to repeat until the escape key is pressed. If you remove the do/while loop, you'll get the behavior you're looking for:

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nWAKE UP."); //repeats forever until
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure if I understand the question rigth, but here the code that would print the msg until any key would be pressed.

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nWAKE UP."); // Repeats forever until

    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        break; //Stop the loop after a key as been pressed
    }
}
```